# What are the security implications of piping apt output compared to apt-get?

Tags: linux, grep, apt, package-management, pipe

I tried to install all python3 packages so that I don't have to manually go to terminal and install one everytime. However due to some dependency issues apt refused to proceed:

```
sonic@boomboom:~$ sudo apt install python3*
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'python3-trufont' for glob 'python3*'
(Long list of packages)
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3-chargebee : Conflicts: python3-chargebee2 but 2.7.3-1 is to be installed
 (Long list of packages)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

So I decided to write a short script that parses the output of `apt`, and automatically installs all packages matching my glob except those that are uninstallable. First I tried `grep` to filter only unwanted packages:

```
sonic@boomboom:~$ sudo apt install python3* | grep 'Conflicts:'

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

 python3-chargebee : Conflicts: python3-chargebee2 but 2.7.3-1 is to be installed
 python3-chargebee2 : Conflicts: python3-chargebee but 1.6.6-1 is to be installed
 (Long list of packages)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Grep did work but a warning pops up, interestingly it does not appear when I use `apt-get` instead.

```
sonic@boomboom:~$ sudo apt install python3* | grep 'Conflicts:'
 python3-chargebee : Conflicts: python3-chargebee2 but 2.7.3-1 is to be installed
 python3-chargebee2 : Conflicts: python3-chargebee but 1.6.6-1 is to be installed
 (Long list of packages)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

The output was exactly the same except for the warning message. What are the security implications of piping `apt` that prompted devs to include a warning? Why does `apt-get` not give the same warning? I believed the two commands were more or less the same thing.

Comment: there are no security implications

Comment: Your last output is from `apt` again, it's not `apt-get`. You don't show anywhere in your question the output of `apt-get` command.

Comment: @JaromandaX there might be, if apt's output changes in a way that causes some rando's script to select a different package for installation or removal than was intended.

Comment: The `--dry-run` option might help for this sort of thing, so you can parse without actually installing.  Also, might want to use `|&` so you pipe the errors?

Answer (score 3):

If you’re not trying to parse its output, `apt` should be safe to use. The main reason for the warning is [that `apt` is intended for interactive use](https://manpages.debian.org/bookworm/apt/apt.8):

> `apt` provides a high-level commandline interface for the package management system. It is intended as an end user interface and enables some options better suited for interactive usage by default compared to more specialized APT tools like `apt-get(8)` and `apt-cache(8)`.

If its output isn’t a terminal, it considers that it isn’t being used interactively and displays a warning. In your case there’s no danger.